# Ubuntu 20.04 and AMD RX 580: frozen black screen on boot

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics

Edit: I no longer have this issue with Ubuntu 22.04. Eventually the only "fix" I found was to wait for two years.

---

I have some problem with my AMD RX 580 with ubuntu (kubuntu flavor, but I tried with a live cd of xubuntu and the exact same issue rise).
First, my system is a dual boot windows / ubuntu. On windows, the AMD drivers are installed, the RX 580 performs just fine.

Linux: Distro: Kubuntu 20.04, kernel: 5.4

The problem: starting the system regularly almost immediately results in a black screen with a "glitched" red horizontal line near the bottom. If I wait a while, the GPUs fan start spinning at full speed for maybe 10 seconds, then stop, and nothing more happens. Impossible to switch to a console with Ctrl + alt + F3, I have not control here.

I can start in low-res only by adding "nomodeset" to the kernel boot parameters. I tried to install the proprietary drivers, alternativly amdgpu and amdgpu-pro. It did not helps. It seems that the card should be supported, but I don't know what to do from there.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
MM.

Answer (score 0):

I am also running an RX580 and have repeatedly had issues throughout the most recent releases (18-22). 20.04 seems to work best for me, but `nomodeset` doesn't seem to work past 18.04

What I have done to get my desktop back is to set a "`amdgpu.dc=0`" flag on a specific line in GRUB and I have included an image with instructions on editing GRUB. If you use `nomodeset`, you should be familiar with the process.

[image: GRUB editing instructions]

You may try the other flags as listed in the image above, but I would stick with the one I suggested, at least at first.

Unfortunately, what this has meant for me is that my HDMI connection has no audio, forcing me to use headphones from one of the audio ports. Not sure if you'll have the same results. I hope this helps you. Seems like RX580s and 480s have some unique problems in Ubuntu.

website for proper attribution:
https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-amd-gpu-black-screen-boot.html

Comment: Thank you. After trying many GRUB launch settings (including amdgpu.dc=0 or 1) found on various post and forums, and what worked for others never worked for me. I dropped the matter for a while. I recently tried with Ubuntu 22.04 without much hope, and suddenly it was working fine. So I guess my problem self-solved over time, and my question is now obsolete.